# How mapping ValueObject in EFCore3.1

Tags: value-objects, ef-core-3.1, abp

The Entity:

```
public class Good : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
{
   ///******///
  public virtual SaleStates SaleStates { get; set; }
}
```

The ModelBuilder:

```
builder.Entity<Good>(b =>
{
  ///******///
  b.OwnsOne(f=>f.SaleStates).WithOwner();
}
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The type 'SaleStates' cannot be marked as owned because a non-owned entity type with the same name already exists.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#config

Comment: Because the AbpDbContext.OnModelCreating() will config the valueobject as non-owned entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is an issue in ABP.
When having this problem, the only thing helped me is using `[Owned]` attribute above the value object's class name.